# How to check if a C# Stream is resizable?

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=VS.90%29.aspx:

> Memory streams created with an unsigned byte array provide a
>   non-resizable stream of the data. When using a byte array, you can
>   neither append to nor shrink the stream, although you might be able to
>   modify the existing contents depending on the parameters passed into
>   the constructor. Empty memory streams are resizable, and can be
>   written to and read from.

When provided a reference to a `MemoryStream` (or even just a `Stream`), how can one check if it's resizable?

The situation arose when using the OpenXML SDK, which requires the streams passed to it be resizable. I can ensure resizability by deep copying to a resizable stream, I'm just wondering if there's a particular reason why the library doesn't throw an exception when a bad parameter is passed to it (i.e. an unresizable stream).

Comment: If you pass in an existing byte array to the `MemoryStream` constructors, the memory stream is merely wrapping the array.  So naturally you can't resize the array and the stream (by extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one kinda ugly way were you catch the NotSupportedException when attempting to resize.

```
public static bool IsResizable(this Stream stream)
    {
        bool result;
        long oldLength = stream.Length;

        try
        {
            stream.SetLength(oldLength + 1);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        if (result)
        {
            stream.SetLength(oldLength);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It's kinda weird that although this distinction exists, there's no property for it. In any case, I'll be copying any stream I receive into a brand new resizable stream I create to ensure resizability.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: the below solution doesn't work for MemoryStreams that were created using the `MemoryStream(byte[], int, int, bool, bool)` constructor with the last parameter `publiclyVisible` set to `true`.

---

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx), `MemoryStream.GetBuffer` will throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` if the object was not created with a "publicly visible buffer".  The constructors listed with publicly visible buffers conveniently map to the sames ones that are resizable.  So you could check that it's re sizable by checking `GetBuffer`:

```
public static bool IsResizable(this MemoryStream stream)
{
    if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

    bool resizable;
    try
    {
        stream.GetBuffer();
        resizable = true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { resizable = false; }

    return resizable;
}
```

Comment: Good to know about the specific parameter in the ctor. Hmmm ... I like the option of trying to `GetBuffer()` rather than attempting to resize. But it would make more sense if the Stream had an appropriate property getter.